# Environment Lock for Automation Anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

Is there anything like Environment Lock of Blue Prism in Automation Anywhere?

Environment Lock is locking a file to be processed by a bot so another bot won't be able to open in.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no environment lock for a file being processed in the current versions of Automation Anywhere.

Version 11 LTS was released last week, and I have not worked in it yet. Not sure if that type of functionality is in the new release.

Answer (score 0):

Automation Anywhere does not have environment lock feature in any version(i.e. 10.x and 11 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

By Default Automation Anywhere does not provide `Environment Locking` concept. But there is an alternate way to do the same.

For implementing `Environment Locking` concept, we need to have a `Global Variable` which is shared between Multibot.

Lets Consider we want to execute, 2 Bots on the same file say `file1.xlsx` and create Global Variable say `isAnyBotUsing?` and set to `false` by default.
Steps would be as below:

Bot 1: Before picking up the `file1.xlsx`, BOT should check `isAnyBotUsing?` variables value. If it is `false` then it should pick the file and set value `true` to `isAnyBotUsing?`. Setting `isAnyBotUsing?` variable to `true` means, any bot is working on the file.

Bot 2: Lets consider, in between BOT 2 gets triggered, and wants to access `file1.xlsx`, then it should check `isAnyBotUsing?` variables value, if it returns `true` BOT 2 should wait till `isAnyBotUsing?` value to `false`

Bot 1: Once the BOT 1 completes its steps to perform on `file1.xlsx` after successfully save and close, it should update the value of `isAnyBotUsing?` to `false`. It means, BOT 1 has released the `file1.xlsx`

Bot 2: It will keep checking the value of `isAnyBotUsing?`, once it returns `false` Bot 2 will pick the file and set the value of `isAnyBotUsing?` to `true`.

But again There is no concept of `Global Variables` in `Automation Anywhere`

We should be either save these variables and there values in excel/notepad/ any file which is needed and suitable.

I would suggest to use the excel, because We can connect excel as Database and can use select and update query on excel to get/set the values in excel.
Another benefit to use of excel is, we're not physically opening the file, we are just querying the file, so n number of BOT can query at a time.